# Restkit & CoreData Error. Failed to call designated initializer on NSManagedObject

Tags: ios, core-data, restkit

I am changing my app from using a purely remote DB to pulling the remote DB into a local DB. I am getting this Error when I am trying to get an Array of Objects from the remote database.

`CoreData: error: Failed to call designated initializer on NSManagedObject class 'Class'`

I am not sure what I am doing wrong. Here is my restkit setup.

```
RKObjectManager *manager = [RKObjectManager managerWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://fake.herokuapp.com"]];
  NSURL *modelURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"App" withExtension:@"momd"];
  NSManagedObjectModel *managedObjectModel = [[NSManagedObjectModel alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:modelURL];
  RKManagedObjectStore *managedObjectStore = [[RKManagedObjectStore alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:managedObjectModel];
  manager.managedObjectStore = managedObjectStore; 

  RKEntityMapping *classMapping = [RKEntityMapping mappingForEntityForName:@"Class" inManagedObjectStore:managedObjectStore]; 
  [classMapping        addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:[Class      propertyMappings]];

  NSIndexSet *statusCodes = RKStatusCodeIndexSetForClass(RKStatusCodeClassSuccessful); 
  RKResponseDescriptor *classDescriptor = [RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:classMapping pathPattern:@"/class.json" keyPath:@"" statusCodes:statusCodes];
  [manager addResponseDescriptorsFromArray:@[classDescriptor]];
  [managedObjectStore createManagedObjectContexts];
   managedObjectStore.managedObjectCache = [[RKInMemoryManagedObjectCache alloc] initWithManagedObjectContext:managedObjectStore.persistentStoreManagedObjectContext];
  [RKObjectManager setSharedManager:manager];
```

And here is the request I am making, where it fails ( i think on the response).

```
    [manager getObjectsAtPath:@"class.json" parameters:nil success:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *mappingResult){
    NSLog(@"Success");

    }failure:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {}];
```

If you need anything else just let me know.
And if you could help out I will be a very happy developer.

Thank you,

-DO

### **EDIT**

This is what propertMappings returns

```
+ (NSDictionary *) propertyMappings{return @{@"id" : @"iD", @"name" : @"name", @"image_url" : @"image_url"};}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well the problem was actually that the Entity I was trying to pull in was nested through a few relationships in my model so it wasn't the parent. It was causing an error. I had to adjust my api a little bit and everything worked.

Thanks for your help.

-DO

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, I suspect that you're going to have issues by having a class called "Class", since "Class" is already a `typedef struct` defined in `objc.h`. I propose refactoring your class name to `ABCClass` or something that isn't reserved.

Secondly, you are adding your attribute mapping by calling `[Class      propertyMappings]`. You should instead do something like this:

```
[classMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{
 @"_id" : @"objectId",
 @"first_name":@"firstName",
 @"last_name":@"lastName"
 }];
```

Don't forget to add `identificationAttributes` to the mapping so as to prevent duplicate objects in Core Data.

Finally, are you creating the actual sqlite file at any stage in your setup? Try the following at the end of your initialisation, just before you call `-(void)createManagedObjectContexts`:

```
[managedObjectStore createPersistentStoreCoordinator];

NSString *storePath = [RKApplicationDataDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"App.sqlite"];

NSError *error;

NSPersistentStore *persistentStore = [managedObjectStore addSQLitePersistentStoreAtPath:storePath fromSeedDatabaseAtPath:nil withConfiguration:nil options:nil error:&error];
NSAssert(persistentStore, @"Failed to add persistent store with error: %@", error);
```

Comment: Class is just the class i am talking about. I didn't want to put what the actual classname was in here. For the second thing, i posted an update with what + (NSDictionary *) propertyMappings; returns

Comment: Okay, that makes more sense. Are you calling [Class new] or [[Class alloc] init] at any point in your code?

Comment: I forgot about doing the last part. But I put it in and I still get the same error.

Comment: I figured out what the problem was. The "Class" Entity was actually nested through a few relationships and wasn't the parent. Its actually a problem with the way my api was set up. Thank you for your help though, I would've probably gotten errors if I had not put it the last part. Also I would mark your answer as the correct one but it would be misleading to the next comer so I will write my own. Thank you =]